# How do I upload custom images to my tab bar in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, image

How do I upload custom images to my tab bar in the iPhone SDK?

I uploaded an image, added it to resources, and tried to make it the image for a tabbar item. This is what happened:

http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?tmn1xtnmjhz

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tab bar icons should be .png files, about 30px square, and should be 24-bit with an alpha channel. All you do is make the image completely transparent except for the part you want to appear as the icon.

You can see some examples here: http://glyphish.com/